# click on word to select and submit as a answer

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to select a word on click and it submits an answer column of the data table after clicking the submit button.

here is my select word code. also, I need to unselect word after click on the selected word.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>Click a word in the paragraph and highlight it.</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
</p>
<textarea name="ans" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
</body>
<script>
var words = $( "p" ).first().text().split( /\s+/ );
var text = words.join( "</span> <span>" );
$( "p" ).first().html( "<span>" + text + "</span>" );
$( "span" ).on( "click", function() {
$( this ).css( "background-color", "red" );
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your result? what error do you get?

Comment: click on text to applying CSS background-color: red., it's working properly but I need to un-select word after click on the selected word.

Answer (score 0):

From comments I red that your problem is that you are unable to unselect words. I have modified your code so it's possible to unselect. Added just one IF to do that:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var words = $( "p" ).first().text().split( /\s+/ );
      var selectedWords = [];
      var text = words.join( "</span> <span>" );
      $( "p" ).first().html( "<span>" + text + "</span>" );
      $( "span" ).on( "click", function() {
        var word = $(this).html();
        if($(this).css("background-color") == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)') {
            $( this ).css( "background-color", "transparent" );
          var index = selectedWords.indexOf(word);
                if (index !== -1) selectedWords.splice(index, 1);
        } else {
            $( this ).css( "background-color", "rgb(255, 0, 0)" );
          selectedWords.push(word);
        }
        $('textarea').html(selectedWords.join(','));
      });
    });
```

Here is also working code: https://jsfiddle.net/42yem8kv/6/

Comment: it's possible when we click on the text to select and then after selected text add in the below textarea?

Comment: Modified the answer. It will now create array of words and than put all selected words to textarea joined with ",". Is that what you wanted?